# $∫\sin^4x\cos^5x\,dx \ \sin x=u$ substitution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).

And hour ago I posted question of $$\int \sin^4x \cos^5xdx$$ Solution was to do $\sin x=u$ substitution.

But if you follow what wiki says $$\int \sin^4x\cos^5x\,dx=\int \sin^4(-x)\cos^5(-x)dx$$ so you should do $\cos x=u$ substitution.

Could you please explain this point? And sorry if this is trivial question.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\int \sin^4(x)\cos^5(x)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4257537/find-int-sin4x-cos5xdx). This was a redone comment.

Comment: I suggest you add a comment asking José Carlos Santos about your question in the previous question.

Comment: Unfortunately the Wiki article is misleading. You need to take into account $dx$. See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3128181/469083 Basically, you substitute $x$ for $-x$ in the $dx$ as well

Comment: Indeed, you accepted the answer to the first time you asked this.  It is inappropriate to ask  the same question 34 minutes after your first question.

Comment: @unit1991 Check this link https://newbedev.com/formulation-of-bioche-s-rules-in-familiar-notation

Comment: @Vasya Thank you I will take a look at it.